# How to find out all time best ranking in SO

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Not sure if this is a duplicate question, How do I find out my all time best ranking? Since ranking move up and down, Is there a way to find out my all time best rank?
In case we do not have it, I suggest we take this as a request proposal and provide this feature for the users.

Comment: Go to [the leagues page](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) and type in your username to filter the users. You can basically then see your ranking.

Comment: Does it give the all time best? May be my rank was #12344 last month and #827 last year. I want to know #827 was my best rank ever in SO.

Comment: @hamza that shows you your **current** rank (without even having to type your name in), but not the **best** rank you've *ever* achieved.

Comment: Sorry my bad _best rank ever_ splipped ...

Comment: At 0:00 UTC one day, I was the top user on all of Stack Overflow for that day. *Can you believe it!?*

Comment: Atleast it would indicate that you were the first user :)

Answer (score 1):

The weekly, monthly, quarterly and yearly leagues keep a history; you can scan through all your rankings and your position in that week / month / quarter / year will be shown at the top. This lets you see historical rankings. Just use the `« prev [period]` and `next [period] »` links shown in the blue box:

[image: previous and next year links]

Your [June 2013 ranking](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2013-06-01/327096?sort=reputationchange#327096), for example, was #35283.

The *overall* league (all time ranking) does *not* have a history, you can only see your current rank.

If you really wanted to know, you could try to reconstruct historical overall rankings based on one of the per-period leagues. These do record *total* score per period; by [the end of 2011](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2011-01-01/327096?sort=reputationchange#327096) your total reputation was 440, for example. Take the reputation for all users in a historical period league ranking and you can calculate your overall ranking for that period yourself.